# Why is 'dir()' named 'dir' in python?

Tags: python, built-in, dir

In Python there is a built-in function called `dir`.  This is used to get a list of all the attributes for an object.

I understand what it does, but I am confused about why it is called `dir`.  How is this name related to getting the attributes from an object?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It gives you a **dir**ectory of all attributes of an object.

This is not a directory as used in file systems, but the standard usage: a listing of names or data.

Comment: I guess I can see this (and you are probably right), but it still strikes me as odd terminology.  Plus, the Python docs don't mention this term anywhere.

Comment: @twneale of course they mention the `dir` function but they don't mention "directory" in any way related to it... the only instance of "directory" on that page is referring to an actual file system directory.

Comment: Sorta like a phone directory

Answer (score 110):

IIRC I named it after the `DIR` command in DOS.

Comment: I can't help but smile when the actual creator gives you a response.

Comment: I appreciate Guido himself gave an explaination on this and further hope that he will continue to reveal the mysteries like the one in here in other places. These are otherwise deadends basically.

Comment: What about using `ls()` as an alias for `dir()`?

Answer (score 4):

You're retrieving a "directory", a list of all of the stuff that's available in some resource.

Answer (score 2):

> This answer will be most useful to those new to Python.

I am learning Python and just this morning was thinking about the builtin constants and functions that are available in the language.

I find it interesting that you only have to remember three things:

> There is a 'special' builtin function *dir()*.
>
> There is a 'system variable' `__builtins__`.
>
> *dir(`__builtins__`)* outputs a view of 'Python's builtin world'.

So what does *dir* mean? I've settled on this for now:

**dir**ections: supplies maps for traversing the Python Landscape.

See also:

[dir(): Display a namespace's names](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/dir-function.html)

So if you want, you could also let dir stand for

*display inside rubric*