# How to find out features of a pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

My question is theoretical. Let's suppose I have a pandas Data Frame in python and I want to check what are the operations which can be performed on it. For e.g. we can perform rename, sum, mean etc. on a pandas data frame. 
But is there any command which will give me the complete list of these kind of operations?

Comment: `dir(pd.DataFrame)` (and `dir` in general).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `dir` command and check all available functions :)

Example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The easiest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command dir to inspect your dataframe -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 'a']], columns =['A', 'B', 'C'])
for d in dir(df)[:10]: print (d)
```

Output (first 10 lines) -

```
A
B
C
T
_AXIS_ALIASES
_AXIS_IALIASES
_AXIS_LEN
_AXIS_NAMES
_AXIS_NUMBERS
_AXIS_ORDERS
```

See more about `dir` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842414/why-is-dir-named-dir-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Well I think there isn't a command to list all available commands, but you can 
install a basic Python Extension to help you out.

If you are using VS Code or Atom just go to Extension Marketplace, there are bunch of them from you can choose.

[image]